# The source code to refresh WebView periodically on Android Studio 3.1.1 doesn't work

Tags: android, android-webview

I get this answer from StackOverflow old question-answer. But when I put it on Android Studio, it comes with an error. How to solve it? Please, take a look at this screenshot and this piece of code:

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings= webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://obs6.com/");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        Toast.makeText(LogThirdPager.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        reload();


    }

    public void reload() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void publish(LogRecord record) {

            }

            @Override
            public void flush() {

            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws SecurityException {

            }
        };
        webView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            Toast.makeText(LogThirdPager.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            reload();
        },5000);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `LogThirdPager.this` in two lines to `MainActivity.this`. `LogThirdPager.this` cannot be referenced from `MainActivity`.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work......[   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   ]..... but this "Hello" notification comes after every 5 sec. Please send a code how to auto refresh my WebView app or can I remotely delete cache...

Comment: You are seeing "Hello" means your code is working and your WebView is also reloaded. If you want to load from beginning, you can disable cache `webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false)`

Comment: It's slow the apps speed. Increase loading speed. is there any process to delete cache when I will change my data on my website or is there any process when mobile will connect with internet app will refreshautomatically.

Comment: You can use `mWebView.clearCache(true);` & `mWebView.clearHistory();`

Comment: it's really slow loading speed sir. It takes more than 9 sec. but my website Gtmatrix speed is 3.8 sec.      Sir my website has a cache plugin. is there any process, if I clear/flush the website cache from admin panel, Then my webview apps will be refresh or cache will be clear.

Comment: I mean when my website content will remain unchanged, my webview App will run on my cache but when I flush cache from my admin panel, Webview app must clear its cache. is it possible.

Comment: You can trigger some calls from your admin panel when you are clearing cache. You can use https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript to bind the code and then trigger `mWebView.clearCache(true)`

Comment: But for the scope of your initial question, the answer I have provided should suffice and make your code running.

Comment: Now I Am using this below code. But its really very slow.             
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
webView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView );
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
 webView.loadUrl( "https://obs6.com/" );
webView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( false );
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
 }

Comment: call webView.loadUrl( "obs6.com/");` at the end in your `onCreate()`

Comment: Yes, I  get this answer but Please solve this slow speed sir.

Comment: If you want it to load faster, then don't clear cache or delete history. InitialLoad might be slow but subsequent loads would be faster.

Comment: I upload new content frequently on my website. So if I, not clear cache user cant get new content. So what can I do. please give me a suggestion